# jQuery - Phonegap multiple pages app for Android?

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I am trying to port an iphone application which is built using HTML5, js, css and jquery to Android. I think I will need a framework like Phonegap to port the app. After porting one html page to Android it seems to take a bit of time before the page is rendered. The screen turns to black screen, which, I guess is due to the reason that Webview is being loaded with the html file. All html files are placed in assets only. Can someone let me know the way of using webview where the black screen is not shown?

Also, I have been trying to search for some examples with jquery - phonegap with multiple pages. By multiple pages I mean there may be different activities for different html files. Can someone point me point me to proper tutorial or example of doing this?

I have seen that the facebook app for Android and iPhone is more or like the same which makes me feel that it may also be html5 app with some native ui used. Even I would like a mixture of native UI elements at some place and html5 functionality at some place.

Comment: I have blogged about using PhoneGap here --
http://subinsebastien.tumblr.com/post/3603378704/phonegap-for-android-noobs Also, I have developed a simple PhoneGap+Jquery application, you can find it here --
https://launchpad.net/droidmnf Check both of the links, and you will have no problem getting it up and running! :)

Comment: Thanks for links. But this are simple tutorials of using Phonegap which I have already gone through. I want to know how to use phonegap, jquery, native UI of Android in one application. There can be multiple activities too.

Comment: You cannot actually use native Android UI via PhoneGap. PhoneGap wraps an Android webView to provide this functionality.

Comment: I think, I will have to use Android's webview and then load html into from assets then rather than using Phonegap. In certain screens, part of UI is html based and part is native UI with native controls. Thanks anyways..

Comment: That is the best approach if you want to access the native controls still when you use some HTML components. Otherwise if can spend some bucks, you can use professional frameworks like Ansca mobile to keep them homogeneous : http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/